# Adding Data to Belongs to resource using TextField laravel Nova

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent, laravel-nova

Hi is there any way to insert data in two tables in one request laravel nova belongsTo relation
What I am trying to achieve is that
I have two models first is the user model & the second one is the student Model
User model has email and password And student model has other profiling details of a student
when a student is created I need to insert a record in the user's table as well and relate that inserted entity with my student detail like some entity go into student details and some in user model related with authentications I am trying to achieve this with laravel nova.

HERE IS USER MODEL RELATIONSHIP WITH STUDENTS

```
 public function students(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\student','user_id','id');
}
```

HERE IS STUDENT MODEL RELATIONSHIP WITH USER

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id');
}
```

I also tried to use nova belongs to field but it gives me dropdown with existing users but I want to create user and student both on the fly in one go and link them with each other
https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/relationships.html#belongsto

I hope i clarify my point thanks if anything feels free to ask or collaborate thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that inside your model, you need to override the save function:

```
public function save(array $options = array()) {
    parent::save($options);
}
```

please note that in order to link your current model to another one, you need to do so after this line parent::save($options); since you can't get the $this->"primary_key" of the current record before actually saving the model in the database

ex:

```
class Student
{
    public function save(array $options = array()) {

        $user = new User();
        $user->property1 = '';
        $user->property2 = '';
        $user->save();

        parent::save($options);

        //Here you can get the $this->studentid
        //Or the $user->userid

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works I can get the attributes by $this variables in save functions